# How to create a new partition from unpartitioned disk space in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

Before I installed Windows 8.1, I had two partitions on my system, one 120 GB and one 200 GB. I deleted the 200 GB partition during the installation, and now I want to create a new equal-size partition in its place. I don't care about the data that was there before. How do I create such a partition so I can use the disk space anew?

Comment: Are you saying you want to create a new partition using that 200 GB of space, and asking how to do that? Note that "recovering" is often taken as meaning you want the data that was there back as well.

Comment: I couldn't find any other word, but I do not want to recover the data. I just want my space back.

Comment: I edited your question to hopefully clarify what you are after. If you feel I changed your intent, feel free to rollback the edit ("edited" link, then "rollback" next to the revision you wish to roll back to). In general, it's fine if you don't know exactly how to express what you want; as long as it's *clear what you want*, someone almost certainly will come along and edit in the proper terminology. However, we can't do that if the intent is unclear.

Comment: Use the built in tool ( the same tool you use to delete the partition ) that is built into Windows.  Its called `Disk Management`

Answer (score -1):

You can easily create a NTFS partition from the deleted partition using the inbuilt partition manger. To do so, right-click on Computer, click Manage and then Disk management. From there, right click on the deleted partition, click New simple volume and follow the instructions.

This is the method to do it on my Windows 7 Computer, so I cannot guarantee that the steps will be exactly the same.

Comment: The prosedure is the same except the last part , New Simple Volume. So I couldn't.

Comment: Could you please tell me what are the options after you right click?

Comment: Could you please check if there is any option related to creating a new partition ie. Create a new NTFS partition.

Comment: It looks in Win8 to be Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management. Unfortunately I don't have any unpartitioned space on the Win8 system so can't check to see exactly what the option is called in the menu.

Comment: Can you post a picture about your disk management?

Answer (score -1):

You can Create new partition by running `gparted`command using `live CD`.and I think it is the best option.

Otherwise if you want to do this in windows then you can do it by `Disk Management (Right Click on My Computer > Manage > Storage > Disk Management)`.

Another option is install [Easeus Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/) (use Home Version it is a free).This will make your problem so easy. You can easily `create/ delete/ merge` new partition easily.